# Prevent duplicates within FOREACH loop/statement

Tags: php, sql

I am using this code to send out emails to my relevent partners, the problem I have is that sometimes the partner ID comes up twice and send the partner 2 x emails (duplicate), how can I prevent this?

```
$get_partner_id = "SELECT partner_id FROM partners_locations WHERE location_id ='$location_id'";

if ($partner_ids = $connect->query($get_partner_id)) {
  foreach ($partner_ids as $partner_id) {
    $partner_id = $partner_id['partner_id'];

    //CONVERT PARTNER IDS TO RELATED PARTNER NAME AND SEND
    $get_partner_names = "SELECT partner_name FROM partners WHERE partner_id ='$partner_id' AND active ='yes'";

    if ($partner_names = $connect->query($get_partner_names)) {
        foreach ($partner_names as $partner_name) {
        $partner_name = $partner_name['partner_name'];

        // GET ADMIN EMAIL TEMPLATE
        ob_start();
        include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/quote/admin-email-template.php'); 
        $admin_message = ob_get_clean();

        @mail("alerts@myremovalsquote.com", "Referral for " . $partner_name . "", $admin_message, $admin_headers);
      }
    } 
    else {

    }                                                           
  }
} 
else {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, simplify your code to just use a single query.  In general, when working with SQL, you don't need loops in the application code.  Use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.partner_name
FROM partners_locations pl JOIN
     partners p
     ON p..partner_id = p.partner_id AND p.active ='yes'"
WHERE pl.location_id = '$location_id';
```

Next, you probably have a data problem, where partners are listed multiple times  in the data, somehow.  You might want to investigate that, if these values should be unique.  In the meantime, you can use `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.partner_name
FROM partners_locations pl JOIN
     partners p
     ON p..partner_id = p.partner_id AND p.active ='yes'"
WHERE pl.location_id = '$location_id';
```